# Disk does not have a configured driver

Tags: laravel, fileupload, storage

Возникает ошибка при загрузке файлов.

> Disk [Тесты тесты.png] does not have a configured driver.

В `config\filesystem.php` сменил `'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 's3')`

Так же после замены выполнил команды
`php artisan config:clear, php artisan cache:clear`

Ругается на файл **`HomeController @ store`**

```php
if ($request->hasFile('otchet') )
    {
     foreach($request->file('otchet') as $index => $otchet){
      $name = ($request->otchet_name[$index]). '.' .$otchet->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $str_otchet = $otchet->store('otchet', $name, 'public');
      $homes->otchet()->create([
            'document' => $str_otchet,
            'document_name' => $name,
            ]);
           }
       }
```

**`FileSystem.php`**

```php
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

**`FileSystem.php S3`**

```php
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],
```

А именно на строчку  `$str_otchet = $otchet->store('otchet', $name, 'public');`
Как я понимаю, в данном месте кода необходимо убрать `'public' или я не  в ту сторону копаю?

Comment: @InDevX, Добавил

Comment: @InDevX, Выполнял (так же указывал в тексте сообщения)

Comment: @InDevX, Добавил файл s3

Comment: store() замените на storeAs()

Comment: @InDevX, Даю Это решает мою проблему. Спасибо.